# I am trying to setup SSL Pinning for React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, tizen, webos

I am creating a react app that will be bundled as packages for WebOS and Tizen OS.

Axios is used for network requests.

So is it possible to set up SSL Pinning for webapps?